# How to display a message from a node method?

Tags: c#, methods, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to display a message to the user informing them whether or not a node has been found in a Doubly Linked List. How do I display the message I want when I call the FindNode method:

```
public Node FindNode(object n) //Find a given node in the DLL
    {
        current = head;
        while ((current != null) && (current.data != n))
            current = current.next;

        if (current == null)
            return null;
        else
            return current;                            
    }
```

Here is my Node class:

```
class Node
{
    public Node prev, next; // to store the links 
    public object data; // to store the data in a node 

    public Node()
    {
        this.prev = null;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(object data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.prev = null;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(object data, Node prev)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.prev = prev;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(object data, Node prev, Node next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.prev = prev;
        this.next = next;
    } 

}
```

Comment: This is a good time to learn about "separation of concerns": it's not the job of the `FindNode` method to print out the result. Its job is to *find a node*. The caller of the method may want to display the result to the user (or write it to a file, or tweet it, or...) but that's up to the caller, not the method itself.

Comment: Also, a small coding quibble: `if (current == null) { return null; } else { return current; }` can be expressed more succinctly as `return current;` :)

Comment: Also it looks like the class that contains FindNode is not thread safe because `current` is not a local variable.

Comment: This is a good time to learn about Framework Libraries http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I appreciate all of your comments, and you are all absolutely right but not one of you answered my question.

Comment: I still need to know how to print the message I want. I get that its not the methods job to print the message, so how to I print the message when I make the call? how do I link the message with that certain call?

Comment: To answer your question - check the value of you call and if it is not null then inform your user with `Console.WriteLine()`, `MessageBox.Show()` or something else - depending on what are you using.

Comment: @JleruOHeP Thank you! I actually tried that before but I forgot to add the name of the doubly linked list in front of the .FindNode()